# Why doesn't WhenEvent work in this case?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

```
yb[a_?NumericQ] := a^2;
eqns = {x'[s] == -yb[s], WhenEvent[x'[s] > 0, {yb[s] -> - yb[s]}], 
  x'[0] == 0}
NDSolve[eqns, x[s], {s, -50, 50}]
```

The `WhenEvent` doesn't evaluate x'[s] correctly, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Is this an example or a real problem?

Comment: this is example,but actually I need to evaluate the sign of first derivative when solving first-order partial differential equation...

Comment: The problem is incorrect, so you need to change the question. Add a real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the functiondefinition yb[a] inside a WhenEvent!

Try

```
eqns = {x'[s] == - sgn[s] yb[s], sgn[0] == +1,WhenEvent[x'[s] > 0, {sgn[s] -> -sgn[s] }], x'[0] == 0}
{X, SGN} =NDSolveValue[eqns, {x, sgn} , {s, -50, 50}, DiscreteVariables -> sgn]
```

Comment: Thanks,this seems perfect for my problem. May I ask some questions for study? 1) why cannot change yb[a] inside WhenEvent?  2) why we need to introduce 
 sgn function into the equation and specify it for DiscreteVariables Option?

Comment: `yb[s]` is an extern function , WhenEvent can only change state variables of NDSolve.